# React history push updating url but not navigating

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router, react-router-dom, history

Following problem:

```
const history = createBrowserHistory()
render() {
    return (
      <Router history={history}>
          <WButton history={history}/>
          <Switch>
               <Route exact path='/' component={Home}/>
               <Route exact path='/next' component={Next}/>
```

When I do this.props.history.push("/next") in WButton Component it only updates the url not switches to Next Component. When I move WButton into Home Component everything works correctly but I'd like to keep WButton on top level. Is this somehow possible?

With `createBrowserHistory({ forceRefresh: true })` it also works on top level but I don't want to reload page with each navigation step.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

I could just use `export default withRouter(WButton)` in the WButton Component instead of the standard export and then remove the manual injection of the history via the props.

Import is `import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';`